# Complex DOM selection jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a structure like this in my DOM:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="truc"></div>
        <div class="machin"></div>
        <div class="chose"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="truc"></div>
        <div class="machin"></div>
        <div class="chose"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="truc"></div>
        <div class="machin"></div>
        <div class="chose"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="truc"></div>
        <div class="machin"></div>
        <div class="chose"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="truc"></div>
        <div class="machin"></div>
        <div class="chose"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="truc"></div>
        <div class="machin"></div>
        <div class="chose"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to select all the ul child (it include the  elements, except the class called "chose". I tried something like:

```
$('ul').children().not('.chose')
```

but i didn't success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `children()` of the `ul` element are `li` elements, not the `div` elements you're after. You need to use [jQuery's `find()` method](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead:

```
$('ul').find('div').not('.chose')
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/amK9b/).

---

> But i want to select the `li` elements to... i want that the complete return be: `<li> <div class='truc'></div> <div class='machin'></div> </li>`

In that case you can use this:

```
$('ul').find('li, div').not('div.chose')
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/amK9b/2/).

Comment: But i want to select the li elements to... i want that the complete return be: 

<li>
    <div class='truc'></div>
    <div class='machin'></div>
</li>

Comment: @Superdrac you can't select the `li` elements without it containing all its children, unless you clone the `ul` and remove all the `.chose` elements - but in doing that you'd be selecting the cloned `ul` and not the current one. What exactly are you wanting to do after selecting those elements?

Comment: @Superdrac see the edit I've made to my answer. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$('ul li')`  . `<li>` are the immediate children of `<ul>`  not`<div>`

```
$('ul li').children().not('.chose')
```

If you want to remove these `<div>`s

```
$('ul li').children('.chose').remove();
```